# Full height div inside td

Tags: css

I want to achieve this thing:
[image]

Height of table row and grey line should be dynamic depend on contents in right column.

I've read in [How to make <div> fill <td> height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542090/how-to-make-div-fill-td-height), so I tried with this http://jsfiddle.net/hyNWy/

But still no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a typo (`width10px;` should be `width:10px;`)... is that just in your question or is it like that in your code as well?

Comment: Code removed here http://jsfiddle.net/hyNWy/. As you can see, the height of div fill out the browser not parent's row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a colon? Also, to get your spacing:

```
<td style="position:relative;">
    <div style="width: 10px; position:absolute; top:10px; bottom:10px; background:grey">
    </div>
</td>
```

#### EDIT:

I don't think it's possible without specifying an explicit height. The solution in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3542090/102441) that you pointed to does not actually work. `position:relative` does not seem to apply correctly to table cells. This could well be intentional and part of the spec.

Comment: Code removed here http://jsfiddle.net/hyNWy/. As you can see, the height of div fill out the browser not parent's row.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with

```
tr {  }
td { position:relative;height:300px; display:block; }
div {
    width:10px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    top:10px;
    display:block;
    background:grey
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyNWy/8/) of that.

Comment: How about this http://jsfiddle.net/hyNWy/10/? The height I defined just example, not fixed. It should be fluid vertically.

Comment: Not a big deal in this case, but link-only answers [are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice) [generally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers) [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).