# Make the background-color of a <div> fill the enclosing <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have an HTML table whose cells contain `div`s with `display:inline-block`, containing text of varying sizes.

I need the text to align on the baseline, and I need the background colors of the `div`s to fill the height of the cells.  For the largest font, the background color *does* fill the cell, but it doesn't for the smaller fonts:

[image: How it looks in Firefox]

Is this possible?  Obvious solutions like `div { height:100% }` seem to be scuppered by the varying font sizes.

Here's the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    table td {
        vertical-align: baseline;
        padding: 0;
    }

    td div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:cyan">
                <div style="background-color:pink;">Pink</div>
                <div style="background-color:green;">Green</div>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color:cyan">
                <div style='font-size: 40pt; background-color:yellow;'>
                    Big yellow text
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It's also on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/gfPkV/).

Comment: If you're already using a table, why not just use table cells?

Comment: @Mathletics: It's complicated.  :-)  I need the `div`s for reasons that aren't obvious from this simplified example.

Comment: Are the font-sizes known values? Can you do the math and work out the padding on the smaller font blocks?

Comment: @Mathletics: Not really.  The HTML is being generated - imagine a PDF-to-HTML conversion program and that's roughly what we're talking about.  (I also don't know in advance which fonts are being used.)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542090/how-to-make-div-fill-td-height

Comment: what's the reason? maybe there is a different approach to this issue

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect, but the closest I could get:

http://jsfiddle.net/gfPkV/14/

Comment: Works great but, in the rare case that a user is zoomed in even a bit it's off again.

Comment: @ptriek: Sadly the text is no longer aligned along the baseline.

Comment: And would it be an option to add an extra div for the fill colour? See my updated link - this preserves baseline alignment (though still a bit messy)

Comment: @ptriek: Lovely in Chrome, but broken in Firefox and IE.  `position:relative`'s behaviour is undefined for `<td>`, and Firefox ignores it.  I'm not sure what IE thinks it's doing, but it's sure not right. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty fix:

**CSS**

```
div {
    line-height:60px;
    height:60px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2YbBg/

Comment: Sadly the text is no longer aligned along the baseline.

Answer (score 1):

I read once, that `td` does not report it's height. So any `height: 100%` or `height:auto`, etc.. won't work.

So my solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/UGTYP/

It changes height of "pink" text to the height of "yellow" div with javascript.

Comment: Sadly, the text is no longer aligned along the baseline.