# Make a <div> fill its parent <td> height, without specifying height on <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542090/how-to-make-div-fill-td-height), but it doesn't work in my case.

```
<table class="Layout">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="Key">HEY</div></td>
            <td><div class="Key">HEY</div></td>
            <td><div class="Key">HEY</div></td>
            <td><div class="Key">HEY</div></td>
            <td><div class="Key">HEY</div></td>
            <td><div class="Key">HEY</div></td>
            <td><div class="Key">HEY</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I make my `div.Key` elements have the same height as their parent `<td>` **without specifying a height to `<td>` elements** ?

My table will dynamically change (adding and deleting columns and rows) so I can't force the `<td>` element to an absolute size, and I would also like not to have to compute and give them a relative size every time I modify the table. The `.Layout` table size also changes dynamically and will always be an absolute value. (For some reasons I would also like not to use row/colspan in case someone suggests that.)

Any idea?

Comment: define your div height min-height:100%;

Comment: Neither min-height nor height are working unfortunatly.

Comment: @The deleted answer : I already tried this, but it doesn't work. The <div> elements are taking the whole viewport size.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by adding an inner div into each `div.Key` and using `display: table; and display: table-cell;` This does what I need. Here is the code:

```
.Layout {
    width: 1024px; /* TEST */
    height: 480px; /* TEST */
}
.Key {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.Key > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And :

```
<table class="Layout">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="Key"><div>HEY</div></div></td>
            <td><div class="Key"><div>HEY</div></div></td>
            <td><div class="Key"><div>HEY</div></div></td>
            <td><div class="Key"><div>HEY</div></div></td>
            <td><div class="Key"><div>HEY</div></div></td>
            <td><div class="Key"><div>HEY</div></div></td>
            <td><div class="Key"><div>HEY</div></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```